# Angular2: angular2/http not found

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have a service trying to make a HTTP request.

When i run angular, i get Angular2/http not found.

> Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/angular2/http(…)

service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import { Http, Response,Headers,HTTP_PROVIDERS,RequestOptions,RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {CommonService} from './common.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  public _productUrl = 'URL-HERE';

  constructor(
private _router: Router,
private _http: Http,
private _commonService: CommonService){}
```

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router'
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS,HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

**app.component,ts**

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: try this type import { Http ,Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

Comment: Looks like you're following an old example. Like @Anuj said, Angular packages now start with `'@angular/'`. If you're following a tutorial, I'd look for a newer one. Likewise, if you're using a starter project. The [official Angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) are not a bad place to start

Comment: ok thats correct, fine.. and one more thing..for the existing code that i have posted, is it good practise for mow to just change the libraries from angular2 to @angular?

Comment: @Sach, you can certainly try, but you'll almost certainly run into issues. I wouldn't do it and you probably don't want to go down this route either. Your `index.html` also refers to an `angular2` folder - if there's something there, it's an old version, which won't work with "@angular" references. If you do not have an existing application you must get running, I'd recommend giving [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io) a try - that should be the easiest way to get started.

Comment: can you please provide us with a copy of your app.module.ts

Comment: Have you checked dependencies

Answer (score 0):

**app.module.ts**

```
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
...
@NgModule({
...
 imports: [
   HttpModule
 ]
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your angular version, if it is below beta.17 you use 'angular2/http'. Normally it is '@angular/http'.
Try to check out the newest documentation.

You can also check this by looking in your node_modules folder. 
You might have a map called @angular instead of an angular2 map.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are importing is not right. You should use following:-

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the following:

```
import { Http, Response,Headers,HTTP_PROVIDERS,RequestOptions,RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
```

Stop using "angular2/http", you should import modules using "@angular/http" because it will point to the latest version on angular in case it changes (we are in angular 4 now). Use this as an example for the future:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try for This:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
and inject into the constructor(private http:Http){}


app.module.ts

import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
...
@NgModule({
...
 imports: [
   HttpModule
 ]
})
...
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this statement

```
import { Http, Response,Headers,HTTP_PROVIDERS,RequestOptions,RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

try once by below import statement follwed by http.

step1: `import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';`

step2: `constructor( private http: Http   ) {}`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Angular CLI We are using.Follow this u can solve problem. Perfect Working for me.

    app.module.ts
    -------------
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      providers: [{
      }],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }

    sample.service.ts
    -----------------

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

    @Injectable()
    export class SampleService {
        public serviceUrl="someURL";
        constructor(private http:Http) {

        }
        doSomeService(bean:any) {
            let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});        
            return this.http.post(
                serviceUrl,
                JSON.stringify(bean),
                {headers: headers}
            ).map(res => res.json())
        }
    }
Try this! Working. Thank you.
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: @WhatsThePoint thanks i will change..     

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
Maybe this line forgot to add app.module.ts file